# Problemas cargar imagenes locales en React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de cargar varias imagenes locales en un componente React a partir de un JSON en que se almacena su ruta.

El componente esta en "src/components/componente-preba/" y las imágenes en "src/assets/images/". Me funcionan las siguientes opciones:

1. Cargarlas con un *import*, indicando la ruta, p.e.:

   `import img3 from '../../assets/images/mlvv.jpg';`

y dentro de `render()`:

```
<img src={img3} />
```

2. Importarlas con *require* dentro del *src*, indicando directamente la ruta:

   `<img src={require('../../assets/images/t2W7d.jpg')} />`

Lo que **estoy intentando es poner estas mismas rutas en un fichero .json**, con un contenido como este:

```
{
    "images": {
        "path1": "../../assets/images/8a1UU.jpg",
        "path2": "../../assets/images/c3F4P.jpg",
        "path3": "../../assets/images/skvIr.jpg"
    }
}
```

importar este fichero en un componente que se lo pasa por *props* al componente que debe *renderizarlas* (este primer componente, el padre, esta en "src/views/componente-padre/"):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ComponentePrueba from '../../components/componente-prueba/ComponentePrueba';
import { images } from './images.json';

class ComponentePadre extends Component
{

    render()
    {

        return(
            <div>
                <ComponentePrueba images={images}></ComponentePrueba>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

En el componente que renderiza las imágenes tengo:

```
render()
{
    console.log(this.props.images.path1);

    return (
        <div className="images-bar">
            <div className="masking-box gradient-to-left">
                <img src={require(this.props.images.path1)} />
                <img src={require('../../assets/images/Rt2W7d.jpg')} />
                <img src={img3} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

y el error que me da el primer *require*:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module
>   '../../assets/images/2IUpoKSP64r6rp2vBo0Fdk8a1UU.jpg'

Answer (score 2):

Yo las guardaría en la carpeta `public` del proyecto, y simplemente usando rutas absolutas con `/file.png` sobre el atributo `src` accedes a ellas.

Nótese que no hace falta especificar el directorio `/public`, al usar la `/` ya estamos accediendo a esa ruta por defecto.

De esta forma te olvidas de importarlas e incluir `require()` en los componentes.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de ReactJs estas usando?
¿Sigue funcionando en el dist?

Comment: Tengo la versión `17.0.1`, no sé si es compatible para todas.

Comment: Prueba a añadir una imagen cualquiera a tu carpeta `public` y mostrarla en algún componente de tu aplicación usando la ruta `/nombreFichero.png`. Debería funcionarte.

Comment: Te puedo confirmar que en *React 16.13* funciona. No responde a la pregunta pero es bueno saberlo.

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo inicial era poner las rutas de las imágenes en un `.JSON` aparte como solución para "limpiar el componente" separando los datos del código dentro de lo posible. A falta de respuestas, aporto una solución parcial, descartando el *JSON*.

Se pasa de tener el siguiente código en la cabecera del componente:

```
import './image-bar.scss';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import img1 from '../../assets/images/2IUpoKSP64r6rp2vBo0Fdk8a1UU.jpg';
import img2 from '../../assets/images/c3F4P2oauA7IQmy4hM0OmRt2W7d.jpg';
import img3 from '../../assets/images/skvI4rYFrKXS73BJxWGH54Omlvv.jpg';
import img4 from '../../assets/images/uLXK1LQM28XovWHPao3ViTeggXA.jpg';
import img5 from '../../assets/images/xOcuDnxTTqNT2CuFNy5VVc67tG4.jpg';

class ImageBar ...
```

seguido más tarde de:

```
<img src={img1} alt="" />
<img src={img2} alt="" />
<img src={img3} alt="" />
<img src={img4} alt="" />
<img src={img5} alt="" />
```

A estos otros:

```
import './image-bar.scss';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Images from './images.jsx';

class ImageBar ...
```

y seguidamente...

```
<img src={Images.IMG1} alt="" />
<img src={Images.IMG2} alt="" />
<img src={Images.IMG3} alt="" />
<img src={Images.IMG4} alt="" />
<img src={Images.IMG5} alt="" />
```

y el nuevo fichero con las rutas locales, que coloco junto al del componente:

```
export const IMG1 = require('../../assets/images/2IUpoKSP64r6rp2vBo0Fdk8a1UU.jpg');
export const IMG2 = require('../../assets/images/c3F4P2oauA7IQmy4hM0OmRt2W7d.jpg');
export const IMG3 = require('../../assets/images/skvI4rYFrKXS73BJxWGH54Omlvv.jpg');
export const IMG4 = require('../../assets/images/uLXK1LQM28XovWHPao3ViTeggXA.jpg');
export const IMG5 = require('../../assets/images/xOcuDnxTTqNT2CuFNy5VVc67tG4.jpg');
```

*Nota: Todo esto se hizo para obtener lo siguiente en una práctica de clase:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]